# How to calculate remaining Days, Hours, Mins and seconds from given date?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

In my app I need to get the days, hours, minutes and seconds from a given date which is coming from JSON response. Below is the date and time i'm getting:

```
"date_time" = "2017-01-31 08:30:00";
```

and need to calculate remaining like days: 6 hours: 18 minutes: 24 seconds: 30

End date will be today's date. I tried below code but it is giving me days in minus (I think it takes UTC timezone) and also tried many answers on SO.

```
NSString *start = [[self.eventsArray valueForKey:@"date_time"]objectAtIndex:0];


NSDateFormatter *date = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[date setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *end = [date stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];


NSDateFormatter *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[f setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *startDate = [f dateFromString:start];
NSDate *endDate = [f dateFromString:end];


NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorianCalendar components:NSCalendarUnitDay
                                                    fromDate:startDate
                                                      toDate:endDate
                                                     options:0];
NSLog(@"day : %ld H: %ld M : %ld S:%ld", [components day], (long)[components hour],(long)[components minute],(long)[components second]);
```

Somebody please help i'm stuck.

Comment: Value of startDate and endDate are dateFromString: start and end will be today's date.

Comment: Take a look at `NSDateComponentsFormatter`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making mistake here, your `fromDate` should be the today date ie `[NSDate date]` and with `toDate` will be your `startDate`. So your code should be something like this.

```
NSString *end = [[self.eventsArray valueForKey:@"date_time"]objectAtIndex:0];

NSDateFormatter *date = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[date setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];    

NSDateFormatter *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[f setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
//Start date
NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];
NSDate *endDate = [f dateFromString:end];


NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorianCalendar components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond
                                                    fromDate:startDate
                                                      toDate:endDate
                                                     options:0];
NSLog(@"day : %ld H: %ld M : %ld S:%ld", [components day], (long)[components hour],(long)[components minute],(long)[components second]);
```

Comment: you mean to say 'NSDate *startDate = [f dateFromString:start];
NSDate *endDate = [f dateFromString:end];'

Comment: @Nij Your from date is today date so that you can get reaming days.

Comment: @Nij You need to also add the components for hour minute and seconds check the edited answer for that.

Comment: thanks for your concern that was my mistake, still getting result like this 'day : 5 H: 9223372036854775807 M : 9223372036854775807 S:9223372036854775807'

Comment: that worked :) Can I know how do I update that value to tableviewcell's label?

Comment: @Nij Welcome mate :)

Comment: @Nij If you want to change time continuously you probably need to use NSTimer for that. Go for it and if it doesn't work post a new question on SO

Comment: @Nij Welcome :) Glad you made it:)

Answer (score 0):

**Call below method and pass your date**

```
+(NSMutableString*) timeLeftSinceDate: (NSDate *) dateT {

    NSMutableString *timeLeft = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];

    NSDate *today10am = [NSDate date];

    today10am = [self getPickerDateForString:[self getPickerDateForDate:today10am]];

    NSInteger seconds = [today10am timeIntervalSinceDate:dateT];

    NSInteger days = (int) (floor(seconds / (3600 * 24)));
    if(days) seconds -= days * 3600 * 24;

    NSInteger hours = (int) (floor(seconds / 3600));
    if(hours) seconds -= hours * 3600;

    NSInteger minutes = (int) (floor(seconds / 60));
    if(minutes) seconds -= minutes * 60;

    if(days) {
        [timeLeft appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld Days ago", (long)days]];
    }else if(hours) {
        [timeLeft appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld h ago", (long)hours]];
    }else if(minutes) {
        [timeLeft appendString: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld m ago",(long)minutes]];
    }else if(seconds) {
        [timeLeft appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Just now"]];
    }

    return timeLeft;
}

+ (NSString *)getPickerDateForDate:(NSDate *)dateVal
{
    NSString * stringVal;
    if (!dateFormatter)
    {
        dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    }
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

    dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];

    stringVal = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateVal];
    return stringVal;
}
+ (NSDate *)getPickerDateForString:(NSString *)dateString
{
    NSDate * stringVal;
    if (!dateFormatter)
    {
        dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    }
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];

    stringVal = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    return stringVal;

}
```